# Split line in bash using comma for elements with space

Tags: bash

I have line like as a parameter for my script

```
 first element,second element,asd,452
```

and I want to split it into array to get

```
 first element
 second element
 asd
 452
```

and be able to access them like array[1]

How can I achieve this?

EDIT:

now I'm trying

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
 echo "Text read from file: $line"
 IFS=, read -ra arr <<< $line
 for x in $arr
  do
    echo "$x"
  done   
done < "$1"
```

my file 
http://pastebin.com/b4RYvUvv

Answer (score 0):

Using `read -a` to read data into array with a custom `IFS`:

```
str='first element,second element,asd,452'
IFS=, read -ra arr <<< "$str"
```

Show content of array `arr`:

```
declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="first element" [1]="second element" [2]="asd" [3]="452")'
```

Comment: `for x in $arr` should be: `for x in "${arr[@]}"`

Comment: this dont work, it gives me full line without commas

Comment: That definitely works. Show your input file by editing the question

Comment: I have added link to sample file

Comment: Now use this script to print data: **`while IFS=, read -ra arr; do for x in "${arr[@]}"; do echo "$x"; done; echo '============'; done < file`**

Comment: Did you try provided script?